# typo in Selberg's "An Elementary Proof of the Prime-Number Theorem"

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am asking about Selberg's [elementary proof](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf).  There seem to be a few key points.  One is his symmetry formula:

$$ \sum_{pq \leq x} \log p \, \log q + \sum_{p \leq x} \log^2 p = 2x \log x + O(x)  $$

Instead let's start from a more basic starting point.  Selberg uses:

$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{x} = \log x + O(1) $$

This would have $\theta(x) = x \log x + O(x)$.  Merten's theorem is a bit different:

$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log x + O(1) $$

Both of them are true I believe.  Which one can be used to show this error term is small?

$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \log p \;\log \frac{x}{p} \stackrel{?}{=} O(x) $$

Hopefully I have copied the statements correctly.

---

Here is the passage I am referring to:

[image]

If I multiply both sides by $x$ I get that $\sum_{p \leq x} \log p = x \log x + O(x)$ which **GH from MO** says is false.  And I don't see why he is using Prime Number Theorem to prove the Prime Number Theorem.

Yet he also says that Merten's theorem is false.  Here is one statement

[image]

and I do not understand the downvoting since the equations I have written are accurate reflection of Mertens' theorem and Selberg's typo.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that Selberg uses the second relation, since it is false: the LHS is $1+o(1)$ by the prime number theorem. Likewise, $\theta(x)=x+o(x)$ by the prime number theorem, and for the error term much better bounds are available (unconditionally and conditionally). A good starting point is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function

Comment: The quoted passage is from the first page of Selberg: An elementary proof of the prime-number theorem, Annals of Math. 50 (1949), 305-313. It contains a typo: Selberg meant $p$ in the denominator, i.e. Mertens' theorem (which is equivalent to (46) at the end of your post). BTW every paper has typos - even the great ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last display in your original post is used in (2.5) of Selberg: An elementary proof of the prime-number theorem, Annals of Math. 50 (1949), 305-313. It is a simple consequence of Chebyshev's estimate $\theta(t)=O(t)$, and it goes as follows:
$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \log p \;\log \frac{x}{p} = \int_{2-}^x\left(\log\frac{x}{t}\right)d\theta(t) = \left[\left(\log\frac{x}{t}\right)\theta(t)\right]_{2-}^x-\int_2^x \left(\log\frac{x}{t}\right)'\theta(t)\,dt.$$
The first term on the right hand side is zero, hence we get
$$ \sum_{p \leq x} \log p \;\log \frac{x}{p} = \int_2^x\frac{\theta(t)}{t}\,dt= \int_2^x O(1)\,dt = O(x).$$
Done.